# Name of a symbol in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm very new to ruby. I have to code in ruby at work and a coworker gave me some tests he wrote in ruby. I have some difficulties to understand a line he wrote.

We have a class like this:

```
class Port
    attr_accessor :nature, :name

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end
```

The test consists in:

```
x_port = Port.new("x")
x_port.nature = :sampling
x_port.wont_be_nil
x_port.nature.name.must_equal :sampling
```

I have some trouble to understand the last line, the `nature.name`. I understand that we are demanding the name of the symbol but this method doesn't exist and I can't create a method name `name` because of the symbol `:name` already there. Can someone enlighten me of how to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but this 'problem' doesn't make much sense. It is either intentionally confusing or there is just some kind of typo.

It is possible in Ruby to open a class and add new methods, like

```
class Symbol
  def name
    self
  end
end
```

which would basically allow `x_port.nature` to return its current value as seems expected in the tests.

This as such would be well worth learning. But putting it into an example where there is another `name` method even if not directly related seems not very smart. So either it's a stupid 'trick' or as said just a typo and the test should look like

```
x_port.nature.must_equal :sampling
```

and then there should be more tests that run on `x_port.name` which is also defined in parallel to `nature` and its value set to "x" in the initializer.